# How to grab specific values in specific lines from the file?

Tags: shell

I have a code

```
for i in $MYCOMP/orderedips/*
do
  if test $old -lt $crazyfunction
```

how do I make the shell check each file and take out content of the second line of the file and then pull out the third and forth value separated by periods to put int the $crazyfunction variable?

i.e: file1

```
blahblahblah
145.384.32.14
```

any possible hints?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the second line, you can do `head -2` to get the first two lines, and then `tail -1` to get the last one:

```
SECOND_LINE=$(head -2 $FILE | tail -1)
```

To split by period, see the `cut` command:

```
echo $STRING | cut -d. -f3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

> how do I make the shell check each file and take out content of the
>   second line of the file and then pull out the third and forth value
>   separated by periods to put int the $crazyfunction variable?

Solution using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
for file in "$MYCOMP/orderedips/"*
    crazyfunction="$(awk -F '.' 'NR==2{print $3"."$4;exit}' "$file")"
    echo "$crazyfunction"
done
```